# If f<g are upper and lower semicontinuous nondecreasing functions, is there some continuous nondecreasing function such that f<h<g?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, monotone-functions, semicontinuous-functions

If $f,g:[0,\infty)\mapsto [0,\infty)$ and $f<g$ are upper and lower semicontinuous nondecreasing functions, is there some continuous nondecreasing function $h:[0,\infty)\mapsto [0,\infty)$ such that $f<h<g?$

First part for $h$ being continuous we know from Michael’s selection theorem for perfectly normal space (https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969615). But what about being monotone?

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: this answer whas to the original question (now changed) where both f and g are upper semicontinuous

---

Maybe I missread, but it seems to me that a continuous $h$ in general does not exist:

Suppose $$f=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 0 & x\in[0,1)\\ 10 & x\geq 1\end{array}\right.$$
$$g=\left\{\begin{array}{cc} 1 & x\in[0,1)\\ 11 & x\geq 1\end{array}\right.$$

If $f<h<g$ then $h(x)\leq 1$ for $x\in[0,1)$ and $h(x)\geq 10$ for $x\geq 1$. So $h$ cannot be continuous.

Comment: My bad, missunderstood the statement. So f is u.s.c and g is l.s.c. Then it should hold. I will review the question.

Comment: Ok, if not both are u.s.c. but one is upper and the other is lower, the it works. You need a simple remark: monotone semicont. functions have only jumps, that is to say, left and right limits always exists. by monotonisity such jumps are countably many. Then f is a sum $f=f_0+\sum f_i$ where $f_0$ is monotone continuous and $f_i$ are jumps functions ($0$ before the jump point, and constant after). For any partial sum you build by hand, recursively, a continuous monotone function $F_i$ between $g$ and $f_0+\sum_{i=0}^k  f_i$. Then you check that $F_i$ uniformly converges to a monotone function.

Comment: Thank you! I have tried to construct in a simillar way by dividing the domain into intervals without jumps, but this is more concise.